# Testing using a guid... how do I set the variable to a Guid?

Tags: c#, variables, .net-2.0, guid

I am testing some db layer functions. In one, I am simulating the user passing in the id (a GUID). I have hardcoded the guid for testing purposes but can't seem to assign it to a variable, as ridiculous as that sounds. In C# for a .NET 2.0 app. I have tried several ways, all failed. What is the proper way to set a guid to a variable? Here is the code...

```
Guid x = "5fb7097c-335c-4d07-b4fd-000004e2d28c";
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
Guid x = new Guid("5fb7097c-335c-4d07-b4fd-000004e2d28c");
```

Comment: Guid Constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you are wanting a random GUID, you can just code `Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();`, and an empty one: `Guid guid = System.Guid.Empty;`

Answer (score 8):

To create a new GUID

```
Guid value = Guid.NewGuid();
```

To create a `Guid` instance from a string

```
new Guid("103C8287-30CB-4630-B3F2-978286F72BD7")
```

To convert a `Guid` object to a string

```
string valueString = value.ToString();
```